# Where can I find Canonical's secure boot certificates?

Tags: uefi, secure-boot, certificates

Where can I find copies of the certificates used by Canonical's secure boot setup?

Specifically, I am looking for the two certificates in the following chain on the bootloader:

```
% sudo sbverify --list /boot/efi/EFI/BOOT/BOOTX64.EFI
signature 1
image signature issuers:
 - /C=GB/ST=Isle of Man/L=Douglas/O=Canonical Ltd./CN=Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority
image signature certificates:
 - subject: /C=GB/ST=Isle of Man/O=Canonical Ltd./OU=Secure Boot/CN=Canonical Ltd. Secure Boot Signing (2017)
   issuer:  /C=GB/ST=Isle of Man/L=Douglas/O=Canonical Ltd./CN=Canonical Ltd. Master Certificate Authority
```

Comment: You would like to find an online source for these certificates? Or somewhere on your boot partition?

Comment: I'm looking for somewhere where I can download the certificates in a standard form (e.g. .PEM).